# pipe leakage in the sink

Tags: leak, drain, pipe, sinkhole

I have this sink in my laundry room, and it started water-leaking a few days ago.

After checking it seemed to me that the joint part between the sink hole and the pipe was a gasket, which was supposed to be air-tight sealed but failed to hold up - water didn't flow down the pipeline, it oozed out from surrounding area of the joint.

I took down the pipe and noticed it says: "c4 CRN tubular f409 1-1/2". I looked up online but didn't find the replacement of the gasket for this pipe.

Do you agree with my diagnosis? Can anyone know where I can find a gasket 
replacement for this type of pipe?

The pipe, the gasket and the sink hole are like below:

[image][image][image]

Comment: The sink drain (metal part) should have some new plumbers putty on its underside, or a new gasket(rubber or foam). The sink drain should sit FLUSH and square, so that the underside is flat when the white plastic pipe is connected. Make sure it (the drain)is adjusted right, and tight. Then put it all back together. The plastic washer you have there looks fine. You can replace it, it doesn't hurt. Then tighten everything back up.

Comment: Agree that the washer looks fine I suspect the leak is from the drain body  not being sealed to the sink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to suggestions from noybman and Kris. You are absolutely right. I bought the sink drain kits and putty from Lowe's and installed it, that fixed the problem.